# How I can get the architecture of the chip in android runtime

Tags: android, cpu-architecture, processor

How I can get the architecture of a snapdragon chip in android runtime ?

I don't have any idea how to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) is a complete list of `System.getProperty()` parameters.